# Unable to push repo to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push repo to GitHub with HTTPs but Git Push command is not working and I am getting this message. I have configured my username and email with  github and both are appearing properly.

```
$ git push
Username for 'https://github.com':
Password for 'https://github.com':
remote: Anonymous access to Azambadar/facerecognitionapp.git denied.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Azambadar/facerecognitionapp.git/'
```

When I right click the folder, GIT Bash here appear in the menu and terminal open when I click Git bash here and then ask me to input my username and password and repo is updated this way.

Any idea how to make work in command terminal ? many thanks

Comment: Are you using [2FA](https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/)?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you have problems with authentication. Maybe your username, password, remote url e.g. two methods can solve this problem,

1. open your terminal and change to root directory of your project, then do

> $ git remote set-url origins [your GitHub project .git url]
>
> $ git push

Then system will ask you to provide your GitHub username and password. Strongly advise you use ssh key for your projects.

2. Go to GitHub project and download the project into preferred path, then do copy and paste of your files into your new cloned project then push.

**maybe you need these commands to set your pushing identifier email and username.**

> $ git config --global user.name [your name]
>
> $ git config --global user.email [your email]